# Auto Airprinting

Tags: automation, airprint

I'm mostly a windows/android user, but I have a new device that works best with airprinting, so please bear with me.

I'm looking to do some 'auto-airprinting'. Basically, what I ultimately what to do is watch a specific folder on a device (whether it be a ipad, or mac) and all new documents in the folder I want to airprint them. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Is there a script or a automation program or...yea. Anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the iOS application called [Workflow](https://workflow.is/). It has a lot of automation abilities including AirPrint.

Comment: Awesome, I'll check it out